# How to get the DeleteParameter value in to the Code behind?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, listview, sqldatasource

I have a ListView that enables deleting, I also use SQLDatasource as DataSource of the ListView, I have these 2 tables:

```
News table that contains news_id, title, etc.. and 
Feedback table that contains feedback_id, comment, news_id(FK), etc...
```

I can delete a record that doesn't have comments but I get this error when I try to delete a News that has a comments, the comments is from the table 'Feedback' that has a foreign key 'news_id' from the table 'News', I know that to resolve this is I need to delete the records from the Feedback table first. How can I achieve it? I'm thinking of using OnItemDeleting Event in ListView and execute a query:

```
DELETE FROM Feedback WHERE news_id = @news_id
```

and then it can proceed to execute the DeleteCommand in the SQLDataSource that is:

```
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [News] WHERE [news_id] = @news_id"
```

but then I got this error:

```
Must declare the scalar variable "@news_id".
```

this is my DeleteParameter:

```
<DeleteParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="news_id" Type="Int32" />
</DeleteParameters>
```

how can i get the news_id from the DeleteParameter?
any answer is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by editing my **Foreign Key Relationships** of my tables, changing the **INSERT and UPDATE Specification** > Delete Rule to **Cascade** from **No Action**. The OnItemDeleting is not needed anymore, I will post this as an answer so if anyone also encounter this problem.

[image]